# Access App SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, access-services

I am setting access apps for SharePoint 2013, I get the following error in the ULS log, Any ideas?? I can't save access Database to custom web app. Much Appreciated.

> ServerSession.ExecuteWebMethodCore: RetryCount: 0, Session=.
>   ProvisionDatabase failed on Proxy Server:
>   Url='http://KRITHSHAREPOINT:32843/b897319197d24b649450a7c943e2b297/AccessService.svc',
>   HS=0, AdjustedHS=0, ServerStateFlags=None, LastReceivedResponse
>   (seconds ago)=0, Unreachable=False, RunningLocally=True.
>   CommunicationException:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DatabaseProviderMessage]:
>   The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason. (Fault Detail is
>   equal to Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DatabaseProviderMessage).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like while provisioning Access DB it's failing. Most likely below option is causing an issue from SQL Side.

**Enable Contained Databases**
In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click the server node and choose properties.  On the General page, there is a property, “Enable Contained Databases”, that you switch to True. Restart SQL Service Post making changes.

**Setting SQL Security Mode**
We also need to set the SQL Security mode to “SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode”.  In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click the server node and choose Properties.  Choose the Security page and choose the “SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode” option. Restart SQL Service Post making changes.